# Explicit Sharing on Facebook iOS SDK 4.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to explicitly share an open graph action on Facebook using the new iOS 4.0 SDK. The following does not work. It shows up on my Activity Log, but not on my Timeline.

```
// Construct an FBSDKSharePhoto
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = img;
photo.userGenerated = YES;

// Create an object
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"theprose:post",
                             @"og:title": post.title,
                             @"og:description": post.text,
                             @"og:caption": @"A fresh picked Prose for you.",
                             @"og:url": post.url,
                             @"fb:explicitly_shared": @"true"
                             };
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *act = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
act.actionType = @"theprose:share";
[act setObject:object forKey:@"theprose:post"];
[act setPhoto:photo forKey:@"image"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = act;
content.previewPropertyName = @"theprose:post";

[[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil] share];
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm running up against the exact same problem.

Comment: I'm having same issue.. in swift 3.. can you post latest code here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Piecing together the answers from this page, this is what worked for me:

**1.  Check the Explicitly Shared box**

Go to your open graph settings, action types and then choose your custom action. Scroll down to capabilities section and make sure that "explicitly share" box is checked.

[image: Capabilities Settings]

**2.  Set fb:explicitely_shared On Action**

```
[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
```

**3.  Set the Relationship Between Action & Object**

Make sure that you know the correct to connect your action to your object.  In this case the key is "article":

```
[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"mynamespace:share" object:object key:@"article"]
```

You can find that key by looking at the Action Type you created in your FB app's Open Graph settings.  When you connected the Action with the Object via a Story, a new key for that relationship appears on the Action's page under the Property Name column.

The original poster is using the namespace:property_name format when what you really need is just the property_name for that key.  This could be the fix for the OP.

**4.  Set the Delegate, Look For Errors**

The OP is not taking advantage of the FBSDKSharingDelegate features.  It reports errors and will help you fix the problem:

```
[[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self] share];
```

And implement the delegate methods in self:

```
#pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate

- (void) sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {

    NSLog(@"Facebook sharing completed: %@", results);
}

- (void) sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Facebook sharing failed: %@", error);
}

- (void) sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {

    NSLog(@"Facebook sharing cancelled.");
}
```

**For Reference, Here's My Working Code**

```
    // Create the object
NSMutableDictionary *properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{
                                                                                   @"og:type": @"mynamespace:article",
                                                                                   @"og:title": myModel.title,
                                                                                   @"og:description": @"myModel.description",
                                                                                   @"og:url": @"http://mywebsite.com"
                                                                                   }];


NSURL *imageURL = [myModel getImageURL];
if (imageURL) {

    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImageURL:imageURL userGenerated:NO];
    [properties setObject:@[photo] forKey:@"og:image"];
}

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create the action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"mynamespace:share" object:object key:@"article"];
[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"article";

// Share the content
FBSDKShareAPI *shareAPI = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
shareAPI.shareContent = content;
shareAPI.delegate = self;

[shareAPI share];
```

Comment: I have code based on yours which does not work - the call [shareAPI share] doesnt result in any of the delegate methods being called. I have posted a seperate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175479/ios-non-dialog-facebook-share-fails-with-no-errors-and-no-feedback - any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: If i already have fb:explicitly_shared , do i need to request publish_actions permission?

Comment: swift 3 version please

Answer (score 1):

The same problem but works fine with FBSDKShareDialog under the same account. So the problem is in something else.

Comment: Same here, I ended up just using the FBSDKShareDialog as well, but I don't really like the app-switching flow. Feels clunky.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I mean the reason in your code is, that you set the fb:explicitly_shared property in the object not in the concerning action.

The following code should solve the issue.

```
[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
```

Comment: I've added but it said it need `publish_actions`

Answer (score 0):

1. If your Facebook app is not public, make sure you have the test account added as a Test account, in the Roles section.
2. Make sure you have requested the publish_actions permission:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions
3. You have no delegate assigned to your call, there is a high chance you are not getting the error returned by Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Go to your open graph settings, action types and then choose your custom action. Scroll down to capabilities section and make sure that "explicitly share" box is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work because there is a bug in FB with SDK versions before 4.1:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/943100005734949/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1563738347248670
but with SDK version 4.1 this bug is fixed but the content for custom story/action/object was shown in very different way in compare with FSDKShareDialog (((

Answer (score 0):

One more check to the checklist: FBSDKShareApi only works on the main thread. So make sure you are sharing from there.