# ios non-Dialog Facebook share fails with no errors and no feedback

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

I have had facebook sharing working fine in my ios app for a year and have upgraded (aka totally rewritten) to use the latest api (4.7.x) and now sharing doesnt work at all. I check that I have publish_actions permission (which I do prior to this method being called, I have 'expicitly shared' checked in open graph settings, action types, capabilities. I am validating the content (I dont get an error) and have a delegate, none of its methods get called.

```
-(void)shareWithFacebook:(NSString *)message
{
    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
    {
        NIDINFO(@"Facebook sharing has publish_actions permission");
    }
    else
    {
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
            handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
            {
                NIDERROR(@"Facebook sharing getting publish_actions permission failed: %@", error);
            }
        ];   
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{
                                                                                   @"og:type": @"article",
                                                                                   @"og:title": @"Bloc",
                                                                                   @"og:description": message,
                                                                                   @"og:url": @"http://getonbloc.com/download"
                                                                                       }];




    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

        // Create the action
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"mynamespace:Share" object:object key:@"article"];
    [action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];

        // Create the content
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"article";

            // Share the content
    FBSDKShareAPI *shareAPI = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
    shareAPI.shareContent = content;
    shareAPI.delegate = self;

    NSError *error;
    if([shareAPI validateWithError:&error] == NO)
    {
        NIDERROR(@"Facebook sharing content failed: %@", error);
    }

    [shareAPI share];
}

 #pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate

- (void) sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NIDINFO(@"Facebook sharing completed: %@", results);
}

- (void) sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NIDERROR(@"Facebook sharing failed: %@", error);
}

- (void) sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NIDINFO(@"Facebook sharing cancelled.");
}
```

I have login working and can get photos fine. I don't get any feedback at all from the facebook api, nothing gets posted. Am I doing something particularly stupid here?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, can you report this at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and attach a small sample project as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility, but I find that Facebook integration has become inconvenient because I find that every time I check the current token for granted permission through `hasGranted:`, it almost always fail even though I gained permission a few minutes ago, or from a previous app launch.

It seems that in your code, if no permission is granted, you try to login and get the permission again. But when that block returns, regardless whether the actual permission is granted or not, you throw an error. Instead, you should continue with sharing if it is successful.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that flaw - I added the permissions check in this method just to be sure I had been granted it, you're right that I need to restructure it once I find out what my problem is. I do have permission so that block isnt executed,  [shareAPI share] does get executed, it just appears to do absolutely nothing